# Fubini theorem for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find a counter example

This is the Fubini theorem for sequences:

> If 
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}|a_{mn}|<\infty,$$
>
> then
>
> $$\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{mn}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}a_{mn}.$$

Then, does there exist a sequence $\{a_{mn}\}$ such that the left and the right hand sides of equality are finite but are not equal?

Answer (score 9):

Fubini's theorem (in the special case of sequences) says that if $\sum\sum|a_{mn}|<\infty$ then interchanging the order of summation in $\sum_m \sum_n a_{mn}$ is acceptable. Note the lack of modulus signs here. In contrast, interchanging the order of summation is *always* acceptable in $\sum\sum |a_{mn}|$, since the summands are nonnegative (this is sometimes called Tonelli's theorem). In this case, equality means that if either side is finite then they both are and they're equal.

If $\sum\sum|a_{mn}|=\infty$, then it may happen that $\sum_m \sum_n a_{mn}$ and $\sum_n \sum_m a_{mn}$ are different, even if they are both finite. Indeed, try summing the rows and columns of the following infinite matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 &\cdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 &\cdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  &\cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't satisfy the condition $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}|a_{mn}|<\infty$, does it?

Comment: @JohnSenior: Such an example is going to be hard to find, as Sean now points out (correctly) in the first paragraph.

Comment: Yes, but I was commenting on Sean's answer before he corrected/explained it :) The initial version seemed to indicate that the example satisfied all the conditions required by the OP.

Comment: I added the absolute values in the second formula of the question, given that the OP missed it at all (he simply write $\sum_m\sum_n=\sum_n\sum_m$).

Comment: @enzotib And you should not have.